# How to export async var from a login

Tags: javascript, authentication, asynchronous, module

I am trying to export user info from login to other modules.

```
  export function login(){

console.log("entrando A LOGIN")    
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

firebase.auth()
.signInWithPopup(provider)
.then((result) => {
  /** @type {firebase.auth.OAuthCredential} */
  var credential = result.credential;      
  var token = credential.accessToken;
  // The signed-in user info.
 let user = result.user;
 module.exports.user=user  /// it says it does not provide user variable when in this ine I am 
 doing it
```

}etc....

/// it says it does not provide user variable but I do it.Thanks I am new

Comment: First - you're mixing commonjs `module.exports` with es6 modules `export function...`. Also, it looks like you're trying to call `module.exports` inside of a `then`. You probably don't wanna do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `module.exports` at all as far as I know. And you really don't want to mix them with es6 modules.

```js
// google-auth.js

export function login() {
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  return firebase.auth()
    .signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then((result) => {
      const credential = result.credential;      
      const token = credential.accessToken;
      const user = result.user;
      return user; 
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // you deal with errors that happen here
    })
}
```

You get the user object by returning it from the function. <s>The function returns a promise though so, if you try and do something like `const user = login()` it's not going to work</s> To import the function into another file and use it in a way that you can access the user object, you'd do something like this:

```js
// login.js

import { login } from './path/to/google-auth.js'

const authInstance = login();
```

From the official docs:

```js
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
  .then((result) => {
    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    const token = credential.accessToken;
    // The signed-in user info.
    const user = result.user;
    // ...
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    const email = error.email;
    // The AuthCredential type that was used.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
    // ...
  });
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')  I couldnt

Comment: Ahh my mistake. I was thinking `firebase.auth()` returned a promise but that's incorrect. It returns an `Auth` instance. See - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.

Comment: Also check this guide from the official docs - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin

Comment: @miguelangelAsencio Try saving the result of calling `firebase.auth()` to a variable and then inspect the properties of the auth object. I think you might find the user info stored there.

Comment: @miguelangelAsencio Let me know what happens. It's been a while since I used firebase on a project. But I think we're on the right track now.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts to help me. The problem for me is to read that information from a second file when importing the function login(), from the login file it is not a problem to read anything, as I need to export for future pages I try to export the login information as the uid. I tried this but didn´t work async function d(){
    const r=await login()
    console.log(r)
  }
    d()